# Sql cursor in infinite loop. What is wrong in this code?

Tags: sql, infinite-loop, database-cursor

Hi I am trying to loop for each employee id in table.

```
BEGIN
declare @empId nvarchar(50)
declare cur Cursor LOCAL for
select EmpId from EmployeeMaster 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @empId
     while @@FETCH_STATUS =0     
      begin      
       select  @empId  
      end   
close cur
END
```

This is my query in stored procedure. What is wrong with this? it is giving me first employee id within infinite loop.
If i check while @@FETCH_STATUS =1 then no output given. just saying
 `Command(s) completed successfully.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `fetch` command after select

```
BEGIN
declare @empId nvarchar(50)
declare cur Cursor LOCAL for
select EmpId from EmployeeMaster 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @empId
     while @@FETCH_STATUS =0     
      begin      
       select  @empId  
       fetch next from cur into @empId
      end   
close cur
END
```

Comment: I just tried that. I got same message "Command(s) completed successfully." rather list of employee in output window

Comment: @RedSwan What do you expected ? I've thought you wanted list of employees.